# Waiting in Pharo v3

Tags: multithreading, smalltalk, pharo

I want to implement a method called `Piece>>userMovesFor:seconds`, which during "seconds" time fetches keyboard input and depending on it, sends some msgs to existing objects to cause them to make some computations (i mean they don't branch the future execution flow).

So from what i know about the system i thought the method could be schematically something like this.

```
Piece>>userMovesFor:seconds
| keyboardInterfacer |
keyboardInterfacer:=KeystrokeInterpreter on:self.
keyboardInterfacer takeKeyboardFocus .
self sleep:40 seconds.
keyboardInterfacer releaseKeyboardFocus .
```

`KeystrokeInterpreter` would be a subclass of `Morph`. While having the focus it would handle the keystrokes through `Morph>>handleKeystroke`.

`Piece>>sleep:seconds` would do nothing but wait "seconds" time.

So at some point of the execution the `Piece` instance would be sleeping doing nothing while the `Morph` instance handles the keyboard input.

My questions are two.

1) Is there a way to implement `Piece>>sleep` such that doesn't cause the system to freeze (so the `KeystrokeInterpreter` instance could do his job)?

I've tried with `Duration>>wait` and also implementing a self calling wait message on my own, but both alternatives freeze the execution of all objects in the image.

2) Is there a better way to implment `Piece>>userMovesFor`?

Comment: I'm not a pro in concurrent things and event handling, but you can read http://pillarhub.pharocloud.com/hub/Uko/concurrentProgrammingInPharo and try to `keyboardInterfacer takeKeyboardFocus` in the fork, maybe it will have some effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using Morphic, #step would be your best bet. You implement it on your Morph, as well as #stepTime (how often to step). As long as your Morph is open in the world, the steps will keep firing. Probably it would be easiest to track the timeout in the Morph too and provide a callback from Piece to pass control back.

Answer (score 3):

40 seconds seems a long time between key presses :)  I haven't looked into key handling before, but this interested me so I poked around.  Maybe you are looking for something like this...

```
Morph subclass: #Piece
    instanceVariableNames: ''
    classVariableNames: ''
    category: 'Play'

Piece>>initialize 
    super initialize.
    self extent: 200@200.
    "Piece new openInWorld"

Piece>>handlesMouseOver: evt
    ^true

Piece>>mouseEnter: event
    super mouseEnter: event.
    self color: Color yellow.
    self takeKeyboardFocus.

Piece>>mouseLeave: event
    super mouseEnter: event.
    self color: Color blue.

Piece>>handlesKeyboard: evt
    ^true

Piece>>keyStroke: event
    event keyCharacter == $r ifTrue:[ self color: Color red ].
    event keyCharacter == $g ifTrue:[ self color: Color green ].
    event keyCharacter == $x ifTrue:[ self delete ].
    event keyCharacter == $c ifTrue: 
    [ 
        [   self inform: 'Starting compute without blocking the UI'.
            (Delay forSeconds: 10) wait. "simulate work"
            self inform: 'Here are the results'.
        ] fork. 
    ].
```

For more information... see how others do it by searching in the Image for senders of the methods implemented above. If you are adventurous, put a 'self halt' in some of those implementations then use "System > Enable halt/inspect once".

Another thread can be found searching google for "[Pharo-users] example custom mouse events"
http://lists.pharo.org/pipermail/pharo-users_lists.pharo.org/2014-August/013156.htm

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Sean idea, make sure you have a look at Morph>>startStepping and the whole stepping and presenter protocol in Morph.

[image: stepping and presenter protocol]

What I would do is to avoid coupling keyboard input and morphs.

Just have morphs step and read keyboard events independently. From there, create announcements to which the Pieces are listening.

Use your game as the announcer.

So, you aren't handling keystrokes but real game related events.

HTH